# How can catch exception on Smart Contract?

Tags: reactjs, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle

**Hello and thank you in advance!**

```
const comprarCapsula = () => {
    const compraCapsula = async () => {

        console.log("Iniciando transacción...");
        // ------------------------
        const pago = web3.utils.toWei(precioFinal.toString(), 'ether');
        // Mensaje de información
        infoAlert();
        // Petición al SC
        const transaction = await contract.myFunction(cantidad, {
            from: props.currentAccount,
            value: pago.toString()}
        ).then((result) => {
            console.log("RESULT:", result);
            successAlert(result.tx);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("TESTING: ", error.message);
            errorAlert(error.message);
        });
        console.log("TRANS: ", transaction);
        // ------------------------
    }

    contract && compraCapsula()
}
```

**My application detects when I cancel the operation with MetaMask (error)** but if the Smart Contract throws an error **it is not picked up by the catch.**

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. 
Object { code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error.", data: {…} }
Data: Object { code: 3, message: "execution reverted: Exception: must have minter role to mint"
```

**Error "must have minter role to mint" its in my Smart Contract.**

Why? I'm trying several ways to collect the RPC errors that Metamask throws but I can't find the way.

Comment: What do you mean with 'cancel the operation' ?

Comment: You're also not yet executing the contract method. In`web3js`, you first setup the "call" as you want to do it with args etc, and then you either execute it locally off chain by doing `call` or on chain by doing `send`. So e.g. `contract.method.Foo().call().on('error', ...)` or `contracts.methods.Foo().send().on('error', ...)`.

Comment: See [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) and [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send).

Comment: @Nearoo Hello and thanks for your help!

My smart contract is handled by truffle-contract which internally does the .call()

The function currently works fine, it just doesn't catch the error that the Smart Contract throws.

If I meet all the requirements the function works fine.
If I reject the transaction in MetaMask it captures it fine.

It just doesn't capture the errors thrown by the Smart Contract.

Comment: Ah sorry. But then it seems you're doing it wrong still. Transactions in truffle don't return promises. Try doing it the way described [here](https://next-stack.github.io/docs/getting_started/contracts#catching-events), where you return the value returned by the method call inside a `then` callback, then attach the error handler to the promise returned by the `then`, not by the method call itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check calling your contract function as such:

```
contract.myFunction.call
```

rather than

```
contract.myFunction
```

I had a similar problem when developing a contract. `call` can be used to see whether the function will throw an error - especially structural, modifier checking wise -  but only using `call` will not invoke the full behaviour of the function. After checking for errors with `call`, you can call the function again.

Function calls with `call` enabled us to catch those kind of errors. I used such a structure then:

```
await contract.myFunction.call(`parameters...`)
     .then(
            contract.myFunction(`parameters...`)
      )
```

Comment: Its working, thanks!!!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help!